# Algebra question :)

Tags: trigonometry

How is:

$\dfrac{140 \cdot \tan 24.5^\circ}{\dfrac{1 - \tan 24.5^\circ}{\tan 31.8^\circ}}$

the same as:

$\dfrac{140 \cdot \tan 24.5^\circ \tan 31.8^\circ}{\tan 31.8^\circ - \tan 24.5^\circ}$

Thank you!

Comment: First of all, welcome to this nice club of ours. Second of all, an unwritten rule in this club is visible effort or participation of members, especially when you ask a question and want to gain knowledge. This context helps you to get what you're looking for and lets us know you're not just using us to complete your homework.

Comment: Lastly, I'm going to rewrite what I think you're asking in MathJax, something that would be useful to learn on this site. If that's it then accept the edit. And for goodness sake add your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hint:

Multiply numerator and big denominator by $\dfrac{\tan 31.8^\circ}{\tan 31.8^\circ}$

You know what happens?

> It cancels out in the denominator

Comment: thank for your sage insights, sir plato!

Comment: You're welcome. If you could honour this sage with an upvote that would be nice.